# Comparing same div class name value using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm finding way how to comparing value on `<div>` on other div tag that has same class name. So, I'm thingking to do it in jquery. Below is example of `<div>` tag that I want to compare ;

```
<div class="helloword" value="4"> </div>
<div class="helloword" value="3"> </div>
<div class="helloword" value="2"> </div>
<div class="helloword" value="1"> </div>
```

I want to make comparasion which which one classes that has smallest value. So it's that possible to do?

Comment: have you tried anything so far? Do you know how to select all the items with the same class and loop through them?

Comment: It's pretty embarrassing but I have no idea how to select all the item, can you suggest me some way how to do it? @ADyson

Comment: it's very basic jquery using selectors...if you have used jQuery or CSS before you can do it. But I will post a solution in case you haven't seen this before

Comment: I'm still newbie to jQuery. That will help me a lot. Thank you. @ADyson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select all the divs by their class, then loop through them and maintain a pointer to the lowest one you've found so far:

```
var lowestVal = 100; //set this higher than your max value
var divs = $(".helloword"); //select all the elements by their class

//loop through each item and compare it to the lowest recorded one
divs.each(function(index, element) {
  var val = parseInt($(element).attr("value"));
  if (val < lowestVal) lowestVal = val;
});
```

Now you can use lowestVal for whatever you need.

Comment: Thank that help me, do edit the error on if statement because I think you forget put the { }. After that I can accept your answer.

Comment: for a one-line if statement in javascript it's valid not to use the brackets - try it :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map()` and `Math.min.apply()` to get min value.

```js
var min = Math.min.apply(null, $('.helloword').map(function() {
  return parseInt($(this).attr('value'))
}))

console.log(min)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="helloword" value="4"></div>
<div class="helloword" value="3"></div>
<div class="helloword" value="2"></div>
<div class="helloword" value="1"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Get all divs using class selector and loop through them using .each() , an untested code as bellow:

```
    var min = 10, minElement = '';
    $('.helloword').each(function(){
        var value = parseInt($(this).attr("value"));
        if (value < min) {
            min = value;
            minElement = $(this);
        }
    });
    // using minElement
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function GetSmallestValue(itemValue)
{
  $(".helloword").each(function (a, b) {
    var newValue = $(this).attr("value");
    if (itemValue==0 || newValue < itemValue) {
      itemValue = newValue;
    }            
  });

  return itemValue;
}

var itemValue = GetSmallestValue(0);
console.log(itemValue);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="helloword" value="4"> </div>
<div class="helloword" value="3"> </div>
<div class="helloword" value="2"> </div>
<div class="helloword" value="1"> </div>
```